# Different behavior of events in different projects

Tags: c++, qt

In the last question, I had a problem with placing the cursor in the right place when clicking on the LineEdit with the mouse.

The problem was solved, I, with God's help, wrote an algorithm that solves my problem. I wrote it in an **EMPTY** project, where there is nothing but LineEdit. Everything worked great there. Here is the code:

```
if(object == ui->lineEdit_newClientPhone && event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) 
{
    QString line = ui->lineEdit_newClientPhone->displayText();
    qDebug() << line;
    ui->lineEdit_newClientPhone->setFocus();
    bool isValid = true;
    for(int i = 0; i<=15; i++){
        if(line[i] == '_'){
            ui->lineEdit_newClientPhone->setCursorPosition(i);
            isValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isValid){
        ui->lineEdit_newClientPhone->setCursorPosition(16);
    }
}
```

It worked great. You click on any place in lineEdit, the mouse cursor is placed on the first empty "_" character. I joyfully ran to transfer it to the main project.

But then I encountered a strange behavior - in the main project, exactly copied code does not give such behavior. When you click on lineEdit with the mouse, the cursor is placed in the place where you clicked. I debugged all the events associated with this LineEdit and found strange behavior - the order of the events is different. Excluding unnecessary events, which were the MOST:

```
if(object == ui->lineEdit_newClientPhone){
    if(event->type() != QEvent::Paint && event->type() != QEvent::MouseMove && event->type() != QEvent::HoverMove){
    qDebug() << event->type();
    }
 }
```

Got this result in "EMPTY" project:

- QEvent::MouseButtonPress
- QEvent::MouseButtonRelease
- QEvent::InputMethodQuery

[image]

But in the main project, the sequence turned out to be different:

- QEvent::MouseButtonPress
- QEvent::InputMethodQuery
- QEvent::MouseButtonRelease

[image]

I don't know if this is the case, but in this way, my logic does not work and the cursor remains in the place where you clicked. I was able to fix the situation by changing the event to QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, but this way I get mocking cursor travels first to the place where you clicked, then to the place I need. What could be the problem and how can it be fixed? Thanks to all!

Comment: Did you see this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532607/qlineedit-set-cursor-location-to-beginning-on-focus

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the right decision, so I would like to hear more solutions, but **QTimer::singleShot** helped me

```
f(object == ui->lineEdit_newClientPhone && event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress){
    QTimer::singleShot(0,ui->lineEdit_newClientPhone,[this]
    {
        QString line = ui->lineEdit_newClientPhone->displayText();
        qDebug() << line;
        ui->lineEdit_newClientPhone->setFocus();
        bool isValid = true;
        for(int i = 0; i<=15; i++){
            if(line[i] == '_'){
                ui->lineEdit_newClientPhone->setCursorPosition(i);
                isValid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isValid){
            ui->lineEdit_newClientPhone->setCursorPosition(16);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Since you can't depend on the order of events, this seems to be a perfectly acceptable way to handle your situation. You could also do it by posting an event to the queue, but that's essentially what a timer with a 0 timeout is.